# Rspec - how to test retries when raising error without using additional gem?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

My code

```
def make_error
  raise StandardError, 'err'
end

class Bob
  def bar(thing)
    puts thing
  end
end

def foo
  ['a', 'b'].each do |x|
    retry_counter = 5
    begin
      bar(x)
      make_error
    rescue StandardError => e
      if retry_counter.positive?
        retry_counter -= 1
        retry
      else
        raise e
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rspec code

```
...
it 'adds and retries the emails to the digest store' do
  expect(Bob).to receive(:bar).exactly(6).times.with('a')
  expect{ foo }.to raise_error(StandardError)
end
```

But the above test fails because the error never gets raised. If I remove the first expectation, then the raise error expectation succeeds, but I want to test the retry logic too. If I just have the 1st expectation, it doesn't retry and exits the code after making 1 iteration.

Comment: `expect { foo }.to raise_error(StandardError)` is too generic. You want `foo` to re-raise the error from `make_error`, not just any error. At least, incorporate the error message via `raise_error(StandardError, 'err')` or better yet, use a custom exception class.

Comment: @Stefan Using :cause can help, but while it works in IRB the backtrace doesn't seem to propagate as expected when run from a file in Ruby 3.3.0. There's probably a way to expand the backtrace or get at `$!` and `$@` better within the rescue clause, but since I agree that the general problems are more structurally deep I didn't spend a whole lot of time trying to figure out why it works properly in the REPL but not at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code gives the following result:

```
Failures:                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                      
  1) foo adds and retries the emails to the digest store                                                                                              
     Failure/Error: expect(Bob).to receive(:bar).exactly(6).times.with('a')                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                      
       (Bob (class)).bar("a")                                                                                                                         
           expected: 6 times with arguments: ("a")                                                                                                    
           received: 0 times
```

This has got **nothing to do with** the logic around raising an exception or the `retry` logic.

The issue is that `bar` is an *instance method* of class `Bob`. So you cannot call it directly (`bar(x)`) from within the `foo` method.

The spec expectation is failing because the method never gets called, and an exception is still being raised, but *not the one you were expecting*:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `bar' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Foo "adds and retries the emails to the digest store"
```

---

It's not entirely clear how one should "fix" this code, but to demonstrate that your setup of using `retry` and `expect(....).to receive(:bar).exactly(6).times.with('a')` does indeed work, here's a valid demonstration:

```
def make_error
  raise StandardError, 'err'
end

class Bob
  def self.bar(thing)
    puts thing
  end
end

def foo
  ['a', 'b'].each do |x|
    retry_counter = 5
    begin
      Bob.bar(x)
      make_error
    rescue StandardError => e
      if retry_counter.positive?
        retry_counter -= 1
        retry
      else
        raise e
      end
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'foo' do
  it 'adds and retries the emails to the digest store' do
    expect(Bob).to receive(:bar).exactly(6).times.with('a')
    expect{ foo }.to raise_error(StandardError)
  end
end
```

As a side note, this is a great example of why it's considered good practice to use custom exception classes instead of relying on `StandardError`.

Answer (score 0):

### Restructure Your Code

First of all, from your code it doesn't look like #foo can reach an instance of Bob so it can call Bob#thing, so I'm not even sure how your code is really supposed to work. I'm going to gloss over that, but you probably have a number of other issues going on.

Other than that, it looks like your basic issue is that you didn't design your methods properly for testability. You need to restructure your #foo method so that you can directly manipulate your retry counter from your specs, and inject different values to help you debug. Treat the following as pseudo-code to give you the general idea:

```rb
# make Bob::bar an endless class method so
# it's reachable from #foo
class Bob
  def self.bar(thing) = (puts thing; thing)
end

def make_error = raise StandardError, "forced failure"

def foo retries=5
  %q[a b].each { Bob::bar _1; make_error }
rescue => e
  (retries -= 1) && retry if retries.positive?
  msg = "no retries left: %p" % { retries: retries }
  raise RangeError, msg, cause: e
end
```

This restructuring does a lot of things:

1. It defines your retries as a positional argument so you can explicitly test specific numbers of iterations with `foo 1`, `foo 0`, or other values to ensure desired behavior and test boundary conditions.
2. It vastly simplifies several methods, especially #foo, making the logic easier to follow.
3. It takes advantage of the implicit begin within your method body to make the code more readable.
4. It provides a more useful error message for debugging than just re-raising *e*, but should still include the **original** unhandled exception in the backtrace as well. It works for me in IRB; YMMV in other code.

### Update Your Specs

You should also ensure your tests are more DAMP. This will help you identify problems more easily. For example, the way you're calling your message expectations is sub-optimal; while you need to set the expectation and then exercise the expectation with code to discover if the expectation is met, you should still avoid mixing other expectations into the same test. I address that along with some other examples below.

```rb
require "rspec"
require "rspec/expectations"
require "rspec/mocks"

RSpec.describe Bob do
  specify do
    expect(Bob).to receive(:bar).with(?a).exactly(5).times
    5.times { Bob::bar ?a }
  end 
end

RSpec.describe "#foo" do
  context "when retries are exhausted" do
    specify { expect { foo 0 }.to raise_error(RangeError) }
    specify { expect { foo 5 }.to raise_error(RangeError) }
    specify { expect { foo 0 }.to raise_error(/no retries left/) }
  end
end
```

You may want to add additional contexts for "with retries remaining" and other such things, but you're going to have to make additional changes to your code to make that work. As it is now, your use of #make_error to test failures instead of injecting a value or stubbing the return from some method like #did_call_fail? makes is hard to create a solid test suite based on the limited code you've provided.

However, this should give you a solid foundation for redesigning your code to be more testable. Rather than hard-coding return values as you're doing in #make_error, injecting a Proc to be evaluated in testing or stubbing the return value of whatever #make_error is really supposed to be doing would be a more robust way to test code without excessive mocking or combining multiple test conditions into each expectation.

As is, I get what I consider sensible results when running the new code against the updated specs:

```rb
$ rspec -fdoc foo.rb

Bob
  is expected to receive bar("a") 5 times

#foo
  when retries are exhausted
    is expected to raise RangeError
    is expected to raise RangeError
    is expected to raise /no retries left/

Finished in 0.00389 seconds (files took 0.03997 seconds to load)
4 examples, 0 failures
```